# POST запрос с помощью JSOUP

Tags: java, android, post, get, jsoup

Есть [сайт](http://schedule.npi-tu.ru/application/prep). На нем нужно узнать расписание преподавателей. Я отследил какие данные откуда идут. Значит:

1. Идёт *GET-запрос* на [http://schedule.npi-tu.ru/ajax/list_prep?term=Алексанян+Г+К](http://schedule.npi-tu.ru/ajax/list_prep?term=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BD+%D0%93+%D0%9A). Отсюда мы получаем три параметра. Их значения: `KFAK`, `KKAF`, `KPERP`
2. Идёт *POST-запрос* на http://schedule.npi-tu.ru/ajax/print_table и мы получаем уже `html` код с расписанием.

Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как осуществить это с помощью *JSOUP*. Я пробовал делать так:

```
private static String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36";

public static void main(String[] args){



        try {
            Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://schedule.npi-tu.ru/ajax/print_table")
                    .userAgent(userAgent)
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .data("KFAK", "A")
                    .data("KKAF", "3")
                    .data("KPREP", "5")
                    .referrer("http://schedule.npi-tu.ru/application/prep")
                    .execute();

            Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();

            Document doc2 = Jsoup
                    .connect("http://schedule.npi-tu.ru/application/prep")
                    .userAgent(userAgent)
                    .cookies(cookies)
                    .get();

            s = doc2.html();
            System.out.println(s);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            tracker = false;
        }
    }
```

Но из этого ничего не вышло.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Получить таблицу можно вот так. А дальше с ней можно работать как угодно.

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://schedule.npi-tu.ru/ajax/print_table")
            .data("KFAK", "A")
            .data("KKAF", "3")
            .data("KPREP", "5")
            .post();

    System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTag("tbody"));
```

Comment: @АндрейСулыз да. расписание выдается в виде html table.